# Pandas - replaces values by other

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a pandas DataFame like this :

```
cols                col1      col2      col3      col4
lines                                                  
l1                  0.004975  0.004975  0.865672  0.99005
l2                  0.004975  0.004975  0.865672  0.99005
l3                  0.004975  0.004975  0.990050  0.99005
l4                  0.004975  0.019900  0.865672  0.99005
l5                  0.004975  0.004975  0.990050  0.99005
l6                  0.004975  0.004975  0.865672  0.99005
l7                  0.004975  0.004975  0.865672  0.99005
l8                  0.004975  0.004975  0.865672  0.99005
l9                  0.004975  0.019900  0.865672  0.99005
```

I want to replace every value by another : if the value is  < 0.025, then it should be to 1, if > 0.0975 then it should be 3, and 2 in every other case.

This code does the job :

```
x = len(list(df.index))
y = len(list(df.columns))

for i in range(x):
    l = df.iloc[i]
    for j in range(y) :
        if l[j] < 0.025:
            l[j] = 1
        elif l[j] > 0.975:
            l[j] = 3
        else:
            l[j] = 2
```

But this is quite ugly and I guess there is a much more elegant and pythonic way to do that ! I'm trying with `loc` and `mask` but no result for now. I also precise that the number and names of lines and columns can vary, so I'm working on a code which works in every case. Can someone show me a better code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with `DataFrame` contructor:

```
m1 = df < 0.025
m2 = df > 0.975

df = pd.DataFrame(np.select([m1, m2], [1,3], default=2), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print (df)
      col1  col2  col3  col4
cols                        
l1       1     1     2     3
l2       1     1     2     3
l3       1     1     3     3
l4       1     1     2     3
l5       1     1     3     3
l6       1     1     2     3
l7       1     1     2     3
l8       1     1     2     3
l9       1     1     2     3
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you :).